# Unable to find ACL information for object identity 'org.springframework.security.acls.domain.ObjectIdentityImpl

Tags: java, spring, grails, groovy, spring-security

**NOTE: This question still has no correct answer!**

I am running Grails 2.4.5 with Spring Security 2.0RC5 and ACL 2RC2. Sometimes I get the following error when I am loggedin with an ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER account.

```
2015-08-28 16:05:17,994 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] ERROR [/majestella].[grails]  - Servlet.service() for servlet grails threw exception
Message: Unable to find ACL information for object identity 'org.springframework.security.acls.domain.ObjectIdentityImpl[Type: majestella.Company; Identifier: 50e396b8eebefc5a84]'
    Line | Method
->>  292 | readAclsById     in grails.plugin.springsecurity.acl.AclService
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     38 | myhotels         in majestella.admin.AdminHotelController
|    198 | doFilter . . . . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter         in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|     32 | doCall . . . . . in Users_mg_Documents_Grails_GGTS3_6_4_Server_majestella_grails_app_views_admin_index_gsp$_run_closure2
|     39 | run              in Users_mg_Documents_Grails_GGTS3_6_4_Server_majestella_grails_app_views_admin_index_gsp
|    198 | doFilter . . . . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter         in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|     53 | doFilter . . . . in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|     62 | doFilter         in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|     46 | doFilterInternal in org.grails.jaxrs.web.JaxrsFilter
|   1145 | runWorker        in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run              in java.lang.Thread
Error |
2015-08-28 16:05:18,035 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NotFoundException occurred when processing request: [GET] /majestella/admin
Unable to find ACL information for object identity 'org.springframework.security.acls.domain.ObjectIdentityImpl[Type: majestella.Company; Identifier: 50e396b8eebefc5a84]'. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag <g:include>: Unable to execute include: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecutionException: Executing action [myhotels] of controller [majestella.admin.AdminHotelController]  caused exception: Runtime error executing action
    Line | Method
->>  527 | doFilter         in /grails-app/views/admin/index.gsp
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
Caused by GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <g:include>: Unable to execute include: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecutionException: Executing action [myhotels] of controller [majestella.admin.AdminHotelController]  caused exception: Runtime error executing action
->>   32 | doCall           in /grails-app/views/admin/index.gsp
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
Caused by ControllerExecutionException: Unable to execute include: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecutionException: Executing action [myhotels] of controller [majestella.admin.AdminHotelController]  caused exception: Runtime error executing action
->>   32 | doCall           in Users_mg_Documents_Grails_GGTS3_6_4_Server_majestella_grails_app_views_admin_index_gsp$_run_closure2
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     39 | run              in Users_mg_Documents_Grails_GGTS3_6_4_Server_majestella_grails_app_views_admin_index_gsp
|    198 | doFilter . . . . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter         in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|     53 | doFilter . . . . in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|     62 | doFilter         in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|     46 | doFilterInternal in org.grails.jaxrs.web.JaxrsFilter
|   1145 | runWorker        in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run              in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecutionException: Executing action [myhotels] of controller [majestella.admin.AdminHotelController]  caused exception: Runtime error executing action
->>  116 | logThrowable     in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     70 | doFilter         in     ''
|     32 | doCall . . . . . in Users_mg_Documents_Grails_GGTS3_6_4_Server_majestella_grails_app_views_admin_index_gsp$_run_closure2
|     39 | run              in Users_mg_Documents_Grails_GGTS3_6_4_Server_majestella_grails_app_views_admin_index_gsp
|    198 | doFilter . . . . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter         in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|     53 | doFilter . . . . in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|     62 | doFilter         in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|     46 | doFilterInternal in org.grails.jaxrs.web.JaxrsFilter
|   1145 | runWorker        in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run              in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ControllerExecutionException: Executing action [myhotels] of controller [majestella.admin.AdminHotelController]  caused exception: Runtime error executing action
->>  198 | doFilter         in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     63 | doFilter         in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|     32 | doCall . . . . . in Users_mg_Documents_Grails_GGTS3_6_4_Server_majestella_grails_app_views_admin_index_gsp$_run_closure2
|     39 | run              in Users_mg_Documents_Grails_GGTS3_6_4_Server_majestella_grails_app_views_admin_index_gsp
|    198 | doFilter . . . . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter         in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|     53 | doFilter . . . . in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|     62 | doFilter         in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|     46 | doFilterInternal in org.grails.jaxrs.web.JaxrsFilter
|   1145 | runWorker        in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run              in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ControllerExecutionException: Runtime error executing action
->>  198 | doFilter         in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     63 | doFilter         in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|     32 | doCall . . . . . in Users_mg_Documents_Grails_GGTS3_6_4_Server_majestella_grails_app_views_admin_index_gsp$_run_closure2
|     39 | run              in Users_mg_Documents_Grails_GGTS3_6_4_Server_majestella_grails_app_views_admin_index_gsp
|    198 | doFilter . . . . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter         in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|     53 | doFilter . . . . in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|     62 | doFilter         in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|     46 | doFilterInternal in org.grails.jaxrs.web.JaxrsFilter
|   1145 | runWorker        in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run              in java.lang.Thread
Caused by InvocationTargetException: null
->>  198 | doFilter         in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     63 | doFilter         in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|     32 | doCall . . . . . in Users_mg_Documents_Grails_GGTS3_6_4_Server_majestella_grails_app_views_admin_index_gsp$_run_closure2
|     39 | run              in Users_mg_Documents_Grails_GGTS3_6_4_Server_majestella_grails_app_views_admin_index_gsp
|    198 | doFilter . . . . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter         in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|     53 | doFilter . . . . in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|     62 | doFilter         in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|     46 | doFilterInternal in org.grails.jaxrs.web.JaxrsFilter
|   1145 | runWorker        in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run              in java.lang.Thread
Caused by NotFoundException: Unable to find ACL information for object identity 'org.springframework.security.acls.domain.ObjectIdentityImpl[Type: majestella.Company; Identifier: 50e396b8eebefc5a84]'
->>  292 | readAclsById     in grails.plugin.springsecurity.acl.AclService
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     38 | myhotels         in majestella.admin.AdminHotelController
|    198 | doFilter . . . . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter         in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|     32 | doCall . . . . . in Users_mg_Documents_Grails_GGTS3_6_4_Server_majestella_grails_app_views_admin_index_gsp$_run_closure2
|     39 | run              in Users_mg_Documents_Grails_GGTS3_6_4_Server_majestella_grails_app_views_admin_index_gsp
|    198 | doFilter . . . . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter         in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|     53 | doFilter . . . . in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|     62 | doFilter         in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|     46 | doFilterInternal in org.grails.jaxrs.web.JaxrsFilter
|   1145 | runWorker        in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run              in java.lang.Thread
```

Using an account with ROLE_USER on the same page I do not get this error.

When I restart the server the error for the ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER user is gone. There might be some caching problem or so.

**How do I fix this error?**

Edit: Here is the GSP I requested:

```
some html code
<g:include controller="adminUser" action="myUsers" />
```

My controller uses Spring Security Annotation:

```
@Secured(AccessRole.ROLE_USER)
class AdminController {
 def index() {}
}
```

Edit: Here is the content of the GSP I include:

```
<%@ page import="test.Hotel" %>


<g:each in="${hotels}" var="hotel">
    <g:render template="hotel" model="[hotel: hotel]" />
</g:each>
```

Comment: Could you show the relevants gsp's and controllers involved?

Answer (score 2):

I still need to see your GSP's at least, but I would bet your problem is related to the use of `<g:include>` and how you are using the SpringSecurity.

Could you try to remove the `<g:include>` tags from your pages and running your tests again?

The problem with that is that Spring Security is implemented with Servlet filters and you're including secured content after the check.

Possible workarounds:

- Try to use Spring Security taglibs with your includes, or don't using
  includes at all.
- Another solution is to refactor your pages to load
  your fragments with ajax.

For example, enclose your *includes* with spring security tags, to show only if the user has the correct roles:

```
<sec:ifAnyGranted roles="ROLE_USER">
   <g:include controller="adminUser" action="myUsers" />
</sec:ifAnyGranted>
```

[]'s

Comment: I updated my post. Without the include tag there are no problems. Do you see any workaround here?

Comment: Ok, so probably you are using Sprint Security with annotations, correct? The problem with that is that  Spring Security is implemented with Servlet filters and you're including secured content after the check.

Maybe if could try to use Spring Security taglibs with your includes, or don't using includes at all.

Another solution is to refactor your pages to load your fragments with ajax.

Comment: Yes please see my edit. Does this helps you or do you need more code?

Comment: The problem with that is that Spring Security is implemented with Servlet filters and you're including secured content after the check. Maybe if could try to use Spring Security taglibs with your includes, or don't using includes at all. Another solution is to refactor your pages to load your fragments with ajax.

Comment: So you say it might work when I do not use Spring Security Annotation on the Class?

Comment: Almost, what I'm saying is that when you use include tag with Spring Security, that's possible to messing things up, because it will be processed after the security filters.

Comment: Sp what else can I do?

Comment: Just added more information in my answer, with an example.

Comment: I tried to use the second suggestion but it gives the same error.

Comment: Could you add some code how you would implement your first idea loading the include page with Ajax?

Comment: Maybe, could you share what is inside the included page?

Comment: Maybe you can try to follow along with this configuration:

https://github.com/uilian/grails-contacts.git

Or, if possible, fork it and try to reproduce the error, push it and so I can see the error happening.

Comment: Still you have not answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

> `Message: Unable to find ACL information for object identity 'org.springframework.security.acls.domain.ObjectIdentityImpl[Type: majestella.Company; Identifier: 50e396b8eebefc5a84]'`

You haven't created the acl entries for `majestella.Company` with id `50e396b8eebefc5a84` in your database. Each records needs to have its permission registered on acl entries and related tables.

Comment: Please read the post carefully. As I said it worked but after a while it does not.

Comment: Yes I did, but the log obviously says that. Have you check the database records? you also mentioned about cache, have you also check that?

Comment: How should I check the cache?

Comment: I use ehcache. How do I check it?

Answer (score 0):

I still have no answer to this question but as a work around I deleted:

```
<g:include controller="adminUser" action="myUsers" />
```